# Why is GetFormattedValue called on a DataGridViewCell that doesn't seem to be properly initialized?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a custom class that inherits from DataGridViewTextBoxCell. In this class I have overridden the GetFormattedValue function.

The second parameter to GetFormattedValue is - according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.getformattedvalue.aspx) - *The index of the cell's parent row.*

In some cases when my function is called this differs from this.RowIndex which - again -    *Gets the index of the cell's parent row.*

Does anybody know when this strange behavior might occur and how to treat it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Turns out that "shared rows" always return -1 as RowIndex (as do column headers which is unnecessarily confusing). Which is probably why this function has a rowIndex parameter in the first place.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx) is a useful link if you are interested in "shared rows".